# Angular 2 DI coding to an interface

Tags: javascript, angular

With the new angular 2 DI we can do this:

```
import HeroService from './HeroService';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(HeroService,{useClass:HeroService})]);
```

There is a way to code to an interface so we can do this?

```
// typescript does not compile interfaces to plain js, we can use this in the provide function?
interface SomeInterface { name: string }

class HeroService implements SomeInterface {}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(SomeInterface,{ useClass: HeroService })]);

// component
class myComponent {

    constructor(hero: SomeInterface) {}

}
```

Comment: If there is support for this

Comment: see my comment below your answer

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202162/interface-based-programming-with-typescript-angular-2-systemjs. I'm not a TS developer but Angular itself seems to use it https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b1b0593ddfc69383d152a592a5e6faaa8647f0e1/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/interfaces.ts#L79 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that such approach is possible since interfaces are erased at runtime in TypeScript and can be referenced.

If you try this in your service:

```
export interface SomeInterface {
  someMethod();
}

export class HeroService implements SomeInterface {
  (...)
}
```

We will have undefined when trying to import it from another module:

```
import {HeroService,SomeInterface} from './hello.service';

console.log('service = '+HeroService); // <---- not null
console.log('interdace = '+SomeInterface); // <---- undefined
```

Here is a plunkr describing this: https://plnkr.co/edit/RT59B0tw40lnq85XMMi7?p=preview.

This answer could also give you some additional hints: [Interface based programming with TypeScript, Angular 2 & SystemJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202162/interface-based-programming-with-typescript-angular-2-systemjs).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It seems it can be done using tokens. See a working version in the next link https://plnkr.co/edit/A6ezGRUlrFsfLr4GjaGi