# An interface cannot be exported in an angular 2 module?

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to export an interface in a NgModule-declaration and export and getting this error already in the editor (Visual Studio Code): `[ts] 'MyInterface' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Here is the example code **Edit-1**:

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }        from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule }     from '@angular/material';
import { MyInterface }        from './my.interface';
import { MyService }          from './my.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, FormsModule,  MaterialModule.forRoot()  ],
  declarations: [ MyInterface],//<- this is causing the message
  exports:      [ MyInterface],
  providers:    [ MyService ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

One part of an explanation I found [in the answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850158/7564182): "since interfaces are erased at runtime in TypeScript".
I'm currently refactoring my app to feature modules, so I cannot test it right now: Can I use the interfaces only by import from './mypathto/my.interface'?

Comment: Post your code. exporting and importing interfaces works just fine here.

Comment: Where do you want to use it? As provider? `I tried to export an interface in a NgModule-declaration` what do you mean?

Comment: Take a look at documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#typescript-interfaces-aren-t-valid-tokens

Comment: I have added the example code to the question. Thanks @yurzui, your link is answering the question: "TypeScript interfaces aren't valid tokens".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot export an interface. You can only export:

1. Other modules
2. Components
3. Directives
4. Pipes

`NgModule` is an angular concept and should not be confused with a typescript module. To make a third party, who uses your module, able to use your interface, you should create a `.d.ts` definition file with your module.

If you want to use a interface inside another NgModule of yours, you should just use:

```
import {InterfaceName} from 'path/to/ngmodule/to/interface';
```

Also, do not put an interface in the declarations array, this is only used for pipes/components/directives.

If you want your interface to be usable outside of an library, you should add it to the export of your `index.ts`:

```
export {InterfaceName} from 'path/to/ngmodule/to/interface';
```

Comment: Thanks PierreDuc for the "complete answer", that clarifies a lot. I found [this documentation on .d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html).

Comment: But, how do I communicate to a third party, that incoming data to a library should follow a certain schema, which I'd like to specify inside an interface? This would make it easier, for example when publishing a node package on npm, would'nt it?

Answer (score 8):

Well actually you can export an interface, but not the way you are trying to do.

First generate interfaces.ts file by typing

`ng g interface <interface_name>`

Example of interface file:

```
export interface Auction{ $key?:string; $auctioneer:string;  ... }
export interface Item{ $key?:string; condition?:string; description?:string; ...}
export interface Bid{  $key?:string;  amount:number;  auction:string; ...}
```

After modifying the file to your needs you can import just one, all or chosen interfaces like this:

```
import { Auction } from './interfaces';
```

or

```
import * as interfaces from './interfaces'; 
// then you have to call interfaces.Auction
```

If per chance you know how to share interfaces globally pls. let me know here: [Angular how to share interfaces across the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075271/angular-how-to-share-interfaces-across-the-app)