# Angular how to share interfaces across the app

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a interfaces.ts file which looks something like this:

```
export interface Auction{ $key?:string; $auctioneer:string;  ... }
export interface Item{ $key?:string; condition?:string; description?:string; ...}
export interface Bid{  $key?:string;  amount:number;  auction:string; ...}
and so on  ...
```

Now I can import those interfaces in each component/service by calling:

```
import { Auction,Item,Bid } from './interfaces';
```

**But how can I import the *interfaces.ts* file so all interfaces will be available globally?**

Comment: globally? can you explain a bit?

Comment: globally - it means in every component or service

Comment: If you will have to use those api defined in interfaces.ts in a component, you have to import them in that component and for other components where they will be needed. If you don't import that in that particular component, you will be flagged with an error 'cannot find name [...]'.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import interfaces.ts in every component/service where you're going to want to use those interfaces.

The closest thing you can do (which saves some writing, maybe) is:

```
    import * as foo from './interfaces';

    var item: foo.Item;
    var auction: foo.Auction;
    var bid: foo.Bid;
```

If you do not import interfaces.ts, it can simply not find the names of the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

In your app module add this, where InterfaceOne and InterfaceTwo  will be your interfaces. The downside to this is that your app module will get bigger the more interfaces you have. It would be better to have the interfaces in a separate file and done in the same way. I'm not sure how to do this though.

```
declare global {

   export interface InterfaceOne {},
   export interface InterfaceTwo {},
   //more interfaces

}
```