# How to export simple TypeScript class in Angular 4 module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module, ng-packagr

I have a simple TypeScript class that I want to package with a module and eventually export that module as a library using `ng-packagr`.

e.g. My class definition is -

```
export class Params {
    language: string ;
    country: string ;
    variant:  string ;
    dateFormat:  string ;
    briefDateTimeFormat:  string ;
    decimalFormat:  string ;
}
```

e.g. My module definition is -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Params } from '../params/params';
import { LoginService } from '../sso/login.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [Params],
  providers: [LoginService]
  declarations: [Params, LoginService]
})
export class FoundationModule { }
```

But when I try to export the `FoundationModule` in `public-api.ts` of `ng-packagr`, I get the following error -

```
BUILD ERROR
: Unexpected value 'Params in .../params/params.ts' declared by the module 'FoundationModule' in '.../foundation.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

How can I package a single class in the Angular module?

Comment: Not sure if you have to create a constructor function to complete the class, the other option is just leave it as a interface.

Comment: i think you need to add export * from '../params/param'. I using this to export my classes for rollup, to get a flat es module

Comment: You're confusing angular modules and es modules. Also, Params should not be a class. Use an `interface`

Answer (score 1):

The two options.

```
export class Params {
language: string;
country: string;
variant: string;
dateFormat: string;
briefDateTimeFormat: string;
decimalFormat: string;
constructor(obj: any) {
    this.language = obj && obj.language || null;
    this.country = obj && obj.country || null;
    this.variant = obj && obj.variant || null;
    this.dateFormat = obj && obj.dateFormat || null;
    this.briefDateTimeFormat = obj && obj.briefDateTimeFormat || null;
    this.decimalFormat = obj && obj.decimalFormat || null;
}
```

}

or

```
export interface Params {
    language: string;
    country: string;
    variant: string;
    dateFormat: string;
    briefDateTimeFormat: string;
    decimalFormat: string;
}
```

and as the first answer says, the classes or interfaces doesn't go on the module.

[Stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332456/an-interface-cannot-be-exported-in-an-angular-2-module)

[Angular reference](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your module definition. You should directly import `Params` into each component/service where the class is required.

**public-api.ts**

```
import { Params } from '../params/params';

...
newVariable: Params = {
  language: 'my language',
  ...
}
```

Comment: Fine iff you make it an `interface` or `type` declaration. That's incorrect use of a class

Comment: @AluanHaddad As he should make it an interface if he doesn't have a constructor! Good catch.

Comment: Perhaps revise your answer but I think he's conflating language and framework concepts as well. Might be good to explain the difference between `import`/`export` and  `@ngModule`'s `imports`/`exports`