# Angular Library for sharing Data Object Models

Tags: angular, module, interface

I am developing an Angular front-end application that sends and receives data from a C# (.NET) back-end server. I am working on sharing data object models between the Angular application (typescript) and backend (C#) - and I am looking for a clean, automated way to keep the two sets of data object models in sync.

As an example, lets say I have a C# interface called "IData", with an attribute "Name". I would like a Typescript interface called "IData" that also has an attribute "Name". If I update the attribute name to something else (say, "LongName"), I want the typescript file to automatically reflect this change. I am ok with a one-way data link (user updates C#, typescript gets updated automatically).

I am currently using Typewriter (https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/) to auto-generate the typescript files from the C# source, and it is doing a wonderful job. The problem that I'm trying to tackle is: what is the best way to share/access the auto-generated typescript files from my angular application?

I have thought about including the auto-generated typescript files into an Angular module in an Angular library project, building it, and then importing it into my Angular application. However, I cannot find a good way to get the library module to automatically include all files in the library (I would like to avoid having to manually update the module file when I create a new data object to share, because these change somewhat frequently), and I am currently using interfaces, which cannot be exported in an Angular module ([An interface cannot be exported in an angular 2 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332456/an-interface-cannot-be-exported-in-an-angular-2-module)).

I have looked into using Typescript modules (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html - different from Angular modules and Javascript modules) and Typescript references (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html), these seem a bit more promising for sharing interfaces but I am still unsure how to use them in this context.

I am using Visual Studio 2017, so ideally the data objects would reside in one visual studio project, and then my angular application would reside in a separate visual studio project, though I understand if this is not possible.

Thanks for any guidance you may have on the right way to do this!

Comment: Why not use a monorepo that includes both projects?

Comment: @Titulum - thanks for the suggestion. Because I'm using Typewriter, I need to share this Data Object library with the C# back-end solution. So if I made this a monorepo, it would have to include my back-end server project, both shared data object projects (C# and typescript), the front-end client project, and all of the referenced framework projects that our group uses. Combing the server and client code is not desirable and I'd like to keep things more cleanly separated if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several months of developing our infrastructure, we decided to go with the Nx Monorepo approach. I am using Nx typescript libraries for each auto-generated typescript project, which are created using Typewriter. An angular module did not make sense for that, because you can't export interfaces from an NgModule, which is the primary type of file I'm trying to export.